# Regarding the application to increase the quota limit for the use of the Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to increase the quota limit for Youtube Data API. If I apply and am approved, how will the fee be paid?
Can I pay with Google Cloud Credits?
Is there a limit to the number of quota applications I can apply for?

Comment: What fee are you referring to

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo
Thank you for responding. I was under the impression there would be a fee for increasing the Youtube Data API quota limit, but it seems I may have been mistaken. Could you clarify if there is a fee associated with requesting a higher quota, and if so, how that payment would be handled? Also, is there a limit to how many times I can request quota increases? I want to make sure I understand the process before applying.